# Mock model in rails is returning array instead of model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

How to write a mock model in rspec which should returns model objects instead of array.

```
let(:item1) { mock_model(Item, item_number: '1') }
let(:item2) { mock_model(Item, item_number: '2') }

let(:items) { [item1, item2]}

inventory.items.order(:number)
```

Unable to use items.order in method, because spec item is returning as array. How to solve this issue

Comment: You are constructing an `array`, which is why you're getting an array. Try, perhaps, `let(:items) { Item.all }`.

Comment: Declared item1 and item2 only should get assigned in items. Item.all  will fetch all the records rit. For testing purposes only two records is enough.

Comment: The only `Item` records in your database during a test should be the `Item` records you create during the test. If your test creates two `Item` records (as you show), then `Item.all` will only return those two `Item` records.

Comment: Ohk let me try it then

Comment: Any luck there?

Comment: ```Item.all``` is returning empty array.

Comment: How are you creating `Item` records in tests? Perhaps there is some validation that is failing and the records are not getting saved in the db.